Spin up MySQL container via docker-compose.yaml, database is created, but tables are not
I want to spin up a MySQL container via my docker-compose.yaml, which looks like this:
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:oraclelinux9
    container_name: mysql_quartz
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: QUARTZ_SCHEMA
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql

On my host machine, I have ./mysql/init.sql which is mounted to container as volume. The init.sql creates the database named QUARTZ_SCHEMA and tables. It looks like this:
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS QUARTZ_SCHEMA;

USE QUARTZ_SCHEMA;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JOBS
(
  SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  JOB_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  JOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRIGGER_GRPS
(
  SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  TRIGGER_GROUP  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);
...

I run docker compose up -d.  The container spun up successfully.  I go to the container and execute mysql commands show databases;, the output shows the expected database QUARTZ_SCHEMA, then, I use the database, and run show tables;, but no tables are created. Why?
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| QUARTZ_SCHEMA      |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> use QUARTZ_SCHEMA;
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)


Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

When starting MYSQL_DATABASE: QUARTZ_SCHEMA cannot be done, because there is not database QUARTZ_SCHEMA at that time ?

The init script needs to be mounted into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ on the right-hand side of volumes:, not somewhere else.  This setup isn't usually a good place to create tables, though, because it only runs if you completely delete the database; use your application framework's database-migration system instead.

Currently the schema is created because of the entry point, not because of your script. ([Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database QUARTZ_SCHEMA)

have you tried this : solution
